# Monitor which website my applications are trying to connect to

Tags: macos, network, monitoring

I am looking for a way to monitor my network so I can know which website that specific application is trying to connect to.

Comment: I'm presuming OS X; if you meant iOS please edit your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/)

Whilst it's mainly a firewall, it alerts you when an app connects to a certain domain, and lets you allow/block the connection.

[image]

Alternatively, you can allow all connections and just monitor them.

[image]

### [Rubbernet](http://rubbernetapp.com)

Rubbernet is also a good alternative, providing the additional feature of remote monitoring of Macs on a network.

[image: Rubbernet monitor]

Answer (score 1):

An excellent monitoring tool for this purpose is Little Snitch.

http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

Macworld gave it 4.5 out of 5 stars ( http://www.macworld.com/product/1250383/little-snitch-3-0-1.html )